# Sfizi as a menu category?

Tags: meaning

Sfizi on Wiktionary https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/sfizi:

> plural of sfizio

Sfizio is defined as

> whimsy, fancy

that doesn’t really explain what it would be as a menu category though.

Any ideas?

Comment: Uno sfizio è un capriccio, una voglia spesso improvvisa. In un menu viene a volte usato in riferimento ai dolci, i dessert.

Comment: @Gio uhhh, English?

Answer (score 6):

*Sfizi* is indeed the plural of the noun *sfizio*, which means “whim, fancy”, or something unusual you desire. In some menus they use it to denote some – in their opinion – especially tasty or sophisticated plates, mainly hors d'oeuvre or desserts. But the use itself is somewhat whimsical: you won't find it in an old-fashioned restaurant.

Comment: Yeah more like appetizers where I saw it

Comment: Whimsy is (also?) a noun in English

Comment: Thanks, @zale. Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with the other answers/comments that it means [treats](http://www.wordreference.com/iten/sfizio), but unlike them I have seen it used almost exclusively as a section of the menu (usually of a cheap eatery such as a pizzeria or a pub) containing deep fried side dishes such as fries, cheese balls and [olive ascolane](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olive_ascolane) --- never for desserts or fancy starters. See for instance [here](http://www.pizzaasportoasti.it/index.php/il-nostro-menu-di-pizze-e-sfizi) or [here](https://www.bizweek.it/uploads/gallery/pizzeria-risorgimento-menu-4.jpg).